# Without using openfiledialog

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to send files to my application without using openfiledialog....lost??

OK.

You select a file in my documents, in the SendTo menu, I want my application to be an option,
when you select my application, the file that was selected should be add to the list box in my application, the same way it would do if I was using openfiledialog. But I want my application to run in the background, which means I don't want to use openfiledialog.

Please help??

Using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for.  You do not need to write any code to get your app in the 'sendTo' menu.  Just following the instructions here:

[HowToGeek - Customize 'Send To' menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/)

once the files / references are being passed to your app, you will have to write code to handle those command line args

Comment: " you will have to write code to handle those command line args" Thats what im struggling with, If you do know, How do i go about doing that. Im new at this, so your help will be appreciated.